# Computing a Gaussian-like integral

Tags: probability, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am given the following joint probability function:

\begin{align}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{2}ye^{-y-\frac{x}{y}} & \text{if} \  x\geq 0 \  \text{and} \  y\geq 0 \\
      0 & \text{else} 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and I'm asked to compute $\Pr(X \leq Y^3)$. So far I have

\begin{align}
\Pr(X \leq Y^3) & = \frac{1}{2} \int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{x=0}^{y^3}ye^{-y-\frac{x}{y}} dx \ dy \\ 
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y}(1-e^{-y^2}) \ dy \\
 & = \frac{1}{2} \left(\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y} \ dy - \int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y-y^2} \ dy\right)
\end{align}

I know that

$$
\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y} \ dy = 2
$$

However, I don't know how to compute the second term. I tried many things such as substitution, multiplying the term by itself and trying to express the integral in polar coordinates, but to no avail. A hint is that I should be able to express the integral in terms of the cdf of the standard normal distribution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you try to fnish the square for the exponent and change variable ? And then use gaussian integral ..

Comment: The last integral may involve the error function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Considering $$I=\int y^2e^{-y-y^2} \, dy$$ first, complete the square
$$y^2+y=\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac 14$$ Now, change variable $t=y+\frac 12$ to make $$I=\frac{\sqrt[4]{e}}{4}\int e^{-t^2} (1-2 t)^2\,dt$$

Comment: Hi Claude. Here it is important to show the new integration limits, because you don't obtain the known constants and need to resort to the error function.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. One more, I agree with you. I just wanted to put the OP on the track.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***

$$e^{-(y^2+y)}=e^{-(y^2+y+1/4)}e^{1/4}=e^{-(y+1/2)^2}e^{1/4}$$

Substitute $z=y+\frac 12$

$$e^{-(y^2+y)}=e^{-z^2}e^{1/4}$$

$$\int y^2e^{-(y^2+y)} \ dy=e^{1/4}\int (z-\frac 12)^2e^{-z^2} \ dz  $$